# Spring Cloud Gateway: Modified Response Body is Truncated

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, gateway, reactor-netty

I've been experimenting with Spring Cloud Gateway a bit and I'm trying to modify the response body.  Using a response decorator, I'm able to see that the body is modified, however, the buffer size is still the size of the original response.  Is there a way to expand the buffer size to the size of the new response body?

```
public class ModifyBodyGatewayFilterImpl implements GatewayFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        logger.info("\n\nexchange.getAttributes():\n {}\n\n", exchange.getAttributes());

        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();

        ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {

                Flux<? extends DataBuffer> flux = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;

                Flux<? extends DataBuffer> f = flux.flatMap( dataBuffer  -> {

                    byte[] origRespContent = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(origRespContent);

                    System.out.println("content::: " + (new String(origRespContent)));

                    //alocating a new buffer size does not help.
                    DataBuffer b = dataBufferFactory.allocateBuffer(256);
                    b.write("0123456789abcdefg".getBytes());

                    return Flux.just(b);
                });

                return super.writeWith(f);
            }
        };

        ServerWebExchange swe = exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build();
        return chain.filter(swe);
    }
}
```

**Example:**  Expected re-written response is `0123456789abcdefg` If original content is 11 bytes `<p>test</p>`, then the re-written response is truncated to `0123456789a`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491098/how-to-add-some-data-in-body-of-response-for-cloud-api-gateway

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue using *buffer()* method:

```java
public class ModifyBodyGatewayFilterImpl implements GatewayFilter {

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {


    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = response.bufferFactory();

    ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(response) {

      @Override
      public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
        if (body instanceof Flux) {
          Flux<? extends DataBuffer> flux = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;

          return super.writeWith(flux.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
            ByteOutputStream outputStream = new ByteOutputStream();
            dataBuffers.forEach(i -> {
              byte[] array = new byte[i.readableByteCount()];
              i.read(array);
              outputStream.write(array);
            });
            outputStream.write("0123456789abcdefg".getBytes());
            return dataBufferFactory.wrap(outputStream.getBytes());
          }));
        }
        return super.writeWith(body);
      }
    };

    ServerWebExchange swe = exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build();
    return chain.filter(swe);
  }
}
```

it should put all response chunks in buffer which should be released when flux is completed.

Comment: I get the exact result with this approach.  Are you able to make this work within the Spring Cloud Gateway?  It's not just an isolated test?  Did you modify the response to be a LARGER response than the initial one?

Comment: Hey @Matt, yes, I was able to make it work with LARGER response.

Comment: Well, if you have it working within the SCG then I don't see what the problem is. Using the most recent SNAPSHOT

Comment: How did you manage to get to the point when writeWith is even called? For me it's never called.  I construct my filters in RouteLocator customRouteLocator. See my comment on https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/1771

Answer (score 3):

you can use this

```
// prepare the mono to be returned
    DataBufferFactory dataBufferFactory = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory();
    ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    byte[] obj;
    try {
        obj = objMapper.writeValueAsBytes(response);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(obj).map(r -> dataBufferFactory.wrap(r)));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
```

where the `response` is any object you want it must be serializable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewrite the `content-length` header also.
Like this:

```
byte[] bytes = "0123456789abcdefg".getBytes();
DataBuffer b = dataBufferFactory.wrap(bytes);
response.getHeaders().setContentLength(bytes.length);
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem, data was received in two buffers. Based on an @Alex solution I've improved it by joining but without `ByteOutpoutStream`.

In my solution I used `DefaultDataBufferFactory` and `join()` method.

```
@Override
public Mono<Void> writeWith(final Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {

    if (body instanceof Flux) {
        Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
        return super.writeWith(fluxBody.buffer().map(dataBuffers -> {
            var joinedBuffers = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().join(dataBuffers);
            
            byte[] content = new byte[joinedBuffers.readableByteCount()];
            joinedBuffers.read(content);
            final var responseBody = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            // modify body
            return bufferFactory.wrap(responseBody.getBytes());
        }));
    }
    return super.writeWith(body);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a general way to modify response (I'm basically modifying the JSON body) without having the need to deal with `Flux` (i.e., `Mono` is fine) so i started to look at what SCG's `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` does today and with the help of the information from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/WeirdBob/b25569d461f0f54444d2c0eab51f3c48) and from [this blog entry](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/spring-cloud-gateway-encryption-decryption-of-request-response-4e76f5b15718).

I was able to come up with a quick-and-dirty solution and wrote it up [here](https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/03550807b1c84100dd028fc8e07950ff).  Basically I just modified what `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` is doing today and change it a little bit for my use case.  A fragment of the solution is here:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {

    Class inClass = String.class;
    Class outClass = String.class;

    String originalResponseContentType = exchange.getAttribute(ORIGINAL_RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE_ATTR);
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, originalResponseContentType);

    ClientResponse clientResponse = prepareClientResponse(body, httpHeaders);

    // TODO: flux or mono
    Mono modifiedBody = extractBody(exchange, clientResponse, inClass)
        .flatMap(originalBody -> Mono.just(applyTransform((String) originalBody, config))
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.empty());

    BodyInserter bodyInserter = BodyInserters.fromPublisher(modifiedBody, outClass);
    CachedBodyOutputMessage outputMessage = new CachedBodyOutputMessage(exchange,
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders());
    return bodyInserter.insert(outputMessage, new BodyInserterContext()).then(Mono.defer(() -> {
        Mono<DataBuffer> messageBody = writeBody(getDelegate(), outputMessage, outClass);
        HttpHeaders headers = getDelegate().getHeaders();
        if (!headers.containsKey(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING)
            || headers.containsKey(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH)) {
            messageBody = messageBody.doOnNext(data -> headers.setContentLength(data.readableByteCount()));
        }
        // TODO: fail if isStreamingMediaType?
        return getDelegate().writeWith(messageBody);
    }));
}
```

Again, this solution may not be what is needed here but hopefully this will help someone who needs a similar solution.