# How to add some data in body of response for Cloud Api Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I'm adding some auth logic into cloud api gateway. I've added GatewayFilter:

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.util.PatternMatchUtils;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class AuthorizationFilter implements GatewayFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(
    ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    List<String> authorization = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization");
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(authorization) &&
      !PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch(URL_WITHOUT_AUTH, exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString())) {
      exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      //Add some custom data in body of the response
      return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
    String token = authorization.get(0).split(" ")[1];
    // token validation
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

but I can't add some data into the body of response. Can you please help me to find out how it works and how I can customize that?

P.S.
I'm trying to add some data in response using flux but it doesn't work:

```java
 DataBuffer b = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().allocateBuffer(256);
      b.write("12345".getBytes());
      return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(s -> Flux.just(b));
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where are you trying to write to response?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question little bit?

Comment: I mean where is the piece of code in P.S. located? what class? is it a filter after handling a request? also, are you using Tomcat?

Comment: I got your question. Actually this piece of code should be inserted into the AuthorizationFilter instead of comment _"//Add some custom data in the body of the response"_. Cloud Api Gateway uses Netty under the cover.

Comment: well I then would try to use [ContentCachingResponseWrapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html). Remember I had such issues when I was writing my own LoggingFilter for Spring MVC

Comment: I'm not sure that we are talking about the same filters. This filter is custom _cloud api gateway_ filter. Response here is _ReactorServerHttpResponse_ and it's reactive response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some help from spring guys, I was able to make it work. So instead of writing directly to response I had to throw my custom exception and handle it properly:

```java
@Bean
public ErrorWebExceptionHandler myExceptionHandler() {
  return new MyWebExceptionHandler();
}

public class MyWebExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> handle(
    ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    byte[] bytes = "Some text".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));
  }
}
```

Comment: how to do this without throwing an exception?

Comment: You don't need to raise exceptions to edit the response body.
See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class AuthorizationFilter implements GatewayFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(
      ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
   if (isAuthorizationTokenValid(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization"))) 
       return chain.filter(exchange);
    exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    //Add some custom data in body of the response,
    //Returning "Unauthorized" in the body here
    return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap("Unauthorized".getBytes())));
  }
  private boolean isAuthorizationTokenValid(List<String> authorizationTokens){
    //Your logic here
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `ServerHttpResponseDecorator` to modify the response.

Your code should be like:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilterChain;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils;
import org.springframework.util.PatternMatchUtils;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponseDecorator;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class AuthorizationFilter implements GatewayFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(
    ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
    List<String> authorization = exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get("Authorization");
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(authorization) &&
      !PatternMatchUtils.simpleMatch(URL_WITHOUT_AUTH, exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString())) {
      exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

      ServerHttpResponse originalResponse = exchange.getResponse();
      DataBufferFactory bufferFactory = originalResponse.bufferFactory();
      ServerHttpResponseDecorator decoratedResponse = new ServerHttpResponseDecorator(originalResponse) {
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
            if (body instanceof Flux) {
                Flux<? extends DataBuffer> fluxBody = (Flux<? extends DataBuffer>) body;
                return super.writeWith(fluxBody.map(dataBuffer -> {
                    // probably should reuse buffers 
                    byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                    dataBuffer.read(content);
                    byte[] uppedContent = new String(content, Charset.forName("UTF-8")).toUpperCase().getBytes();
                    return bufferFactory.wrap(uppedContent);
                }));
            }
            return super.writeWith(body); // if body is not a flux. never got there.
        }           
      };
      return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decoratedResponse).build()); // replace response with decorator
    }
    String token = authorization.get(0).split(" ")[1];
    // token validation
    return chain.filter(exchange);
  }
}
```

You can find [a complete example here](https://gist.github.com/WeirdBob/b25569d461f0f54444d2c0eab51f3c48).

Comment: in this case request will be sent by chain to the end service, but I need to stop processing request in this filter.

Comment: Modified Response Body is Truncated