# How to modify the response body in Spring Cloud Gateway just before the commit

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using Spring Cloud Gateway with Spring 5, Spring Reactor and Netty for a project. For every request send to the gateway I want to do something just before the response is sent to the client. The best way I have found to do it is to add an action to the response with the beforeCommit method.

I first tried this approach :

```
        exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            try {
                myActionDoneHere();
                response.setStatusCode(OK);
                return Mono.empty();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                return Mono.error(new MyException(ex));
            }
        });
```

And tried to handle the exception in an exception handler :

```
public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
    if (isMyException(ex)) {
     exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentLength(MSG.length());
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(MSG.getBytes())));
    }

    return Mono.error(ex);
}
```

When I do that I have an exception when I try to modify the content length. If I understand well the situation. I can't modify the response anymore in my handler because the it as been already committed. So I tried an other solution and tried to modify the response in my action executed just before the commit :

```
exchange.getResponse().beforeCommit(() -> {
    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
    try {
        myActionDoneHere();
        response.setStatusCode(OK);
        return Mono.empty();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getHeaders().setContentLength(MSG.length());
        response.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
        return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(MSG.getBytes())));
    }
});
```

This time I don't have any exception, I can modify the content length but I can't modify the body of the response.

So does someone know if it's possible to do so and How ?

Comment: I used the debugger to try to understand what's happening and it seems the body is written by the last filter which is NettyWriteResponseFilter. So just before the commit it's already too late, the body is no more available. But what's confusing is that I still have access to the headers. So If someone has an idea and know how to run a piece of code that can modify the response before it is validated and sent to the client I'd really like to know.

Comment: May be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491098/how-to-add-some-data-in-body-of-response-for-cloud-api-gateway but the answer doesn't help because it only handles exceptions

Answer (score 6):

I used the technique that was inside `WebClientWriteResponseFilter`

```
    if (failedAuthorization) {
        ServerWebExchangeUtils.setResponseStatus(exchange, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        ServerWebExchangeUtils.setAlreadyRouted(exchange);
        final Map<String, String> error = Map.of("error", "unauthorized");
        return chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.defer(() -> {
            final ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8.toString());
            return response.writeWith(new Jackson2JsonEncoder().encode(Mono.just(error),
                response.bufferFactory(),
                ResolvableType.forInstance(error),
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8,
                Hints.from(Hints.LOG_PREFIX_HINT, exchange.getLogPrefix()))
            );
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It's unbelievable how complicated it is to add a simple response message...

Answer (score 4):

Spring Cloud gateway now has filters to modify request body and response body.
[ModifyResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#modify-a-response-body-gatewayfilter-factory)
[ModifyRequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#modify-a-request-body-gatewayfilter-factory)

Comment: As noted in the documentation you linked, this can only be used using the Java DSL configuration (i.e., cannot use YAML).

Comment: @DexterLegaspi You can't use properties to define the filter out of the box because it needs a function to indicate how you want to modify the body. However, you can create a custom filter using in turn one of these filters, defining the function, and then yes use the custom filter in your YAML setup. An example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71888244/6661361

Comment: @GerardoRoza i guess the bottomline you _still_ create a custom filter...you cannot use the the`ModifyResponseBody`/`ModifyRequestBody` filters out of the box...when i needed something that supports YAML config, i ended up doing something like [this](https://gist.github.com/dalegaspi/03550807b1c84100dd028fc8e07950ff)...your approach is actually simpler, though...using Adapter pattern...i like it.  I also found a similar solution to what you have which used inheritance which i thought was pretty clever...but for the life of me i cannot find it...it's in one of those threads in github.com