# Spring Cloud Gateway for composite API calls?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud

I am starting to build a Microservice API Gateway, and I am considering Spring Cloud to help me with the routing. But some calls to the Gateway API will need multiple requests to different services.

Lets say I have 2 services: **Order Details Service** and **Delivery Service**. I want to have a Gateway endpoint ***GET /orders/{orderId}*** that makes a call to **Order Details service** and then **Delivery Service** and combine the two to return full Order details with delivery. Is this possible with the routing of Spring cloud or should I make these by hand using something like RestTemplate to make the calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an enhancement proposal posted on GitHub to [have routes support multiple URIs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/114). So far, there aren't any plans to implement this yet, at least, not [according to one of the contributors](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/114#issuecomment-461065450).

Comment: So, what you are saying is, it is not yet possible to do what i want and I should stick with standard controllers for these composite endpoints? Would using rest template be best practice?(all microservices are rest)

Comment: I just found about ProxyExchange, which can serve this purpose instead of relying on RestTemplate.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__building_a_simple_gateway_using_spring_mvc_or_webflux.html

Comment: @D.Tomov Great! That's what they also recommended on using within the issue I linked within my answer.

Comment: @D.Tomov could you please advise how you proceeded for this?

Answer (score 2):

As posted in the Spring Cloud Gateway Github issue [mentioned by g00glen00b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55574687/6661361), until the library develops a Filter for this, I resolved it using the `ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory` in my own custom Filter.

Just in case it's useful for anyone else, I provide the base implementation here (it may need some rework, but it should be enough to make the point).

Simply put, I have a "base" service retrieving something like this:

```
[
  {
    "targetEntryId": "624a448cbc728123b47d08c4",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "sadasa",
        "description": "asda"
      }
    ],
    "id": "624a448c45459c4d757869f1"
  },
  {
    "targetEntryId": "624a44e5bc728123b47d08c5",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "asda",
        "description": null
      }
    ],
    "id": "624a44e645459c4d757869f2"
  }
]
```

And I want to enrich these entries with the actual `targetEntry` data (of course, identified by `targetEntryId`).

So, I created my Filter based on the ModifyResponseBody one:

```
/**
 * <p>
 *   Filter to compose a response body with associated data from a second API.
 * </p>
 *
 * @author rozagerardo
 */
@Component
public class ComposeFieldApiGatewayFilterFactory extends
    AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ComposeFieldApiGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

  public ComposeFieldApiGatewayFilterFactory() {
    super(Config.class);
  }

  @Autowired
  ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyFilter;

  ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>> jsonType =
      new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {
      };

  @Value("${server.port:9080}")
  int aPort;

  @Override
  public GatewayFilter apply(final Config config) {
    return modifyResponseBodyFilter.apply((c) -> {
      c.setRewriteFunction(List.class, List.class, (filterExchange, input) -> {
        List<Map<String, Object>> castedInput = (List<Map<String, Object>>) input;
        //  extract base field values (usually ids) and join them in a "," separated string
        String baseFieldValues = castedInput.stream()
            .map(bodyMap -> (String) bodyMap.get(config.getOriginBaseField()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        // Request to a path managed by the Gateway
        WebClient client = WebClient.create();
        return client.get()
            .uri(UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost").port(aPort)
                .path(config.getTargetGatewayPath())
                .queryParam(config.getTargetQueryParam(), baseFieldValues).build().toUri())
            .exchangeToMono(response -> response.bodyToMono(jsonType)
                .map(targetEntries -> {
                  // create a Map using the base field values as keys fo easy access
                  Map<String, Map> targetEntriesMap = targetEntries.stream().collect(
                      Collectors.toMap(pr -> (String) pr.get("id"), pr -> pr));
                  // compose the origin body using the requested target entries
                  return castedInput.stream().map(originEntries -> {
                    originEntries.put(config.getComposeField(),
                        targetEntriesMap.get(originEntries.get(config.getOriginBaseField())));
                    return originEntries;
                  }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                })
            );
      });
    });
  }

  ;

  @Override
  public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("originBaseField", "targetGatewayPath", "targetQueryParam",
        "composeField");
  }

  /**
   * <p>
   * Config class to use for AbstractGatewayFilterFactory.
   * </p>
   */
  public static class Config {

    private String originBaseField;
    private String targetGatewayPath;
    private String targetQueryParam;
    private String composeField;

    public Config() {
    }

    // Getters and Setters...

  }
}
```

For completeness, this is the corresponding route setup using my Filter:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        # TARGET ENTRIES ROUTES
        - id: targetentries_route
          uri: ${configs.api.tagetentries.baseURL}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/target/entries
            - Method=GET
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/target/entries(?<segment>.*), /target-entries-service$\{segment}
        # ORIGIN ENTRIES
        - id: originentries_route
          uri: ${configs.api.originentries.baseURL}
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/origin/entries**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/api/origin/entries(?<segment>.*), /origin-entries-service$\{segment}
            - ComposeFieldApi=targetEntryId,/api/target/entries,ids,targetEntry
```

And with this, my resulting response looks as follows:

```
[
  {
    "targetEntryId": "624a448cbc728123b47d08c4",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "sadasa",
        "description": "asda"
      }
    ],
    "id": "624a448c45459c4d757869f1",
    "targetEntry": {
      "id": "624a448cbc728123b47d08c4",
      "targetEntityField": "whatever"
    }
  },
  {
    "targetEntryId": "624a44e5bc728123b47d08c5",
    "sections": [
      {
        "title": "asda",
        "description": null
      }
    ],
    "id": "624a44e645459c4d757869f2",
    "targetEntry": {
      "id": "624a44e5bc728123b47d08c5",
      "targetEntityField": "somethingelse"
    }
  }
]
```