# Spring boot Gateway Post filter won't modify response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

```
public class FileBrowserPostFilter implements GatewayFilter, Ordered {
    @Autowired
    private Gson gson;

    @Autowired
    private FileBrowserService fileBrowserService;

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(exchange)
                .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
                    var request = exchange.getRequest();
                    var response = exchange.getResponse();
                    String requestMethod = request.getMethod().name().toUpperCase();
                    var status = response.getStatusCode();

                    if (requestMethod.equals("POST") && status.is2xxSuccessful()) {
                        String path = request.getPath().subPath(4).value();
                        var newItem = this.fileBrowserService.getItem(path);
                        var newItemJson = this.gson.toJson(newItem);
                        response.setRawStatusCode(201);
                        DataBuffer dataBuffer = response.bufferFactory()
                                .wrap(newItemJson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                        response.writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer));
                        exchange.mutate().response(response).build();
                    }
                }));
    }
}
```

asume fileBrowserService will always return a valid item
I am expecting the filter to
change status code to 201 (successful)
modify the response body to something like so:

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "path": "/1/name.jpg",
        "name": "name.jpg",
        "size": 503627,
        "extension": ".jpg",
        "modified": "2023-07-12T11:55:22.440578974-04:00",
        "mode": 493,
        "type": "image",
        "sharedUsers": [],
        "public": false,
        "dir": false,
        "symlink": false
    }
```

but it keep returning it original response body

```
200 ok
```

which should not happening
does anyone know why?

I have try all these solution here
https://wankhedeshubham.medium.com/spring-cloud-gateway-modify-response-body-using-global-post-filter-1dbe0a077f8e
[Spring Cloud Gateway - modify response body in global Post filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72127761/spring-cloud-gateway-modify-response-body-in-global-post-filter)
and it is not working.

Comment: You're trying to modify the HTTP response after the response *has already been committed*, which can't be done. You need to handle it at the `pre` or `post` phase intstead, by intercepting the response before it's sent back to the client

Comment: I thought Mono.fromrunable is Handle in post phase? How should I access this post phase before commit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.